Настроить смену url при смене города на проекте Larvel SPA
На проекте Laravel SPA/VUE создан сайт с маршрутами в api.php. Пользователь на главной странице может с помощью выпадающего списка, созданного на VUE, выбрать город, в котором находится предприятие. Города сохранены в базу данных и отдаются в SPA по запросу на api/cities из контролера. При выборе города происходит смена названия сайта, и ряд блоков, что также реализовано на VUE. Необходимо выборе города из выпадающего списка добавлять в url название города. Сейчас такой смены не происходит. То есть пользователь выбрал в выпадающем списке Челябинск. Нужно в url добавить https://пример.рф/челябинск. Выбрал город Наро-Фоминск в url добавилось https://пример.рф/нарофоминск. Можете объяснить куда копать? Мое предложение на VUE динамически добавлять в url название города, а на Laravel в middleware буду отлавливать название города и объединю все маршруты под соответствующую группу.

Вам нужно сначала точно определиться - нужны ли вам адреса типа https://пример.рф/челябинск (например чтобы их давать/сохранять пользователям). Или вам нужен "одноадресный" SPA https://пример.рф и при выборе из списка менять только специализированный блок для Города - для этого достаточно использовать конструкцию   https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#component

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html
